# In android image is not loading from localhost(127.0.0.1)

Tags: android, tomcat, localhost

In my program when i pass a image url of any image on internet it showing image>>>

Like

```
new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://www.mayoff.com/5-01cablecarDCP01934.jpg");
```

it's working fine.

but when we use localhost address of any image it not working....

```
new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://127.0.0.1/Travel/images/raj.jpg");
```

**in this line image is not loading from localhost server....**

does AVD not works with Localhost??

Comment: OK may be I am wrong, but didn't you miss the tomcat port number in the url ?

Comment: try to change ip address to 10.0.2.2

Comment: @ShashankKadne yse sir, i have tried  with port number 127.0.0.1:80 also but not working

Comment: @JiteshDalsaniya with ip address 10.0.2.2 it's working fine ..thanks..plz elobrate something logic behind it in answer??

Comment: This has been designed in this way by the Android team. So your webserver can perfectly run at localhost and from your Android app you can access it via "http://10.0.2.2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is however a far better solution. You can access your host machine with the IP address `10.0.2.2`.

This has been designed in this way by the Android team. So your webserver can perfectly run at localhost and from your Android app you can access it via `http: //10.0.2.2`